# C++ - Returning Value in Boolean then validate it

Tags: c++

Today I start to learn c++ a bit and I begins to understand with simple code, but this make confuse me

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyVar
{

    public:
        MyVar(){
            cout << "this is constructor" << endl;
        }
        void accesscheckpass(string x){
            checkpass(x);
        }

    private:
        bool checkpass(string x){
            if(x == "password"){
                return true;
            }
        }
};

int main()
{
    int inputpass;
    cout << "please enter your password\n" << endl;
    cin >> inputpass;

    MyVar MyAccess;

    if(MyAccess.accesscheckpass(inputpass) == true){
        cout << "welcome user 1" << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "get lost !" << endl;
    }

}
```

I want to validate the user when he/she entered the password, then when to section IF, when I want to compile it, compiler return the status "invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]|", please someone repair my code and explain what i'm wrong ?

Comment: Check about what line the compiler complains, then look what function you call there, and compare the type the function expects with the type you pass it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> please someone repair my code

Try to repair it yourself after we explain what's wrong. You'll gain much more from it than by us posting your code.

> explain what i'm wrong

Sure. The method `accesscheckpass` expects a `std::string` as parameter (btw you need to `#include <string>` at the top of the file). You call it as

```
MyAccess.accesscheckpass(inputpass)
```

but `inputpass` is declared as `int inputpass;`, so it's and `int`, not a `std::string`. So you either have to declare `inputpass` as a `string` or find out how to convert an `int` to a `string`. (should be easy)

Also, your method:

```
    bool checkpass(string x){
        if(x == "password"){
            return true;
        }
    }
```

only returns if the condition is true. You should have an `else` branch as well:

```
    else
        return false;
```

or, better yet, return the result directly.

```
    bool checkpass(string x){
        return x == "password";
    }
```

and your method

```
    bool accesscheckpass(string x){
       return  checkpass(x);
    }
```

should return a `bool` as well.

Comment: so many mistake i make, very shame, and thank you for your detail explanation... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class MyVar
{

    public:
        MyVar(){
            cout << "this is constructor" << endl;
        }

            bool accesscheckpass(string x){
            return checkpass(x);
        }

    private:
        bool checkpass(string x){

            if( x == "password" ){
                return true;
            }
            else
            return false;
        }
};

int main()
{
    string inputpass;
    cout << "please enter your password\n" << endl;
    cin >> inputpass;

    MyVar MyAccess;

    if( MyAccess.accesscheckpass(inputpass) == true ){
        cout << "welcome user 1" << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "get lost !" << endl;
    }

}
```

Above is the corrected working code. The spotted errors are as follows:

1. "invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]|" because you passing int to function whose parameter is a string type argument so the data type of the inputpass has been changed.
2. accesscheckpass() is returning nothing so i have the returned the returning value of checkpass(). checkpass() is dealing with the true condition only so false consition is added.

Answer (score 0):

`accesscheckpass(string x)` should return bool.

```
bool accesscheckpass(string x){
        return checkpass(x);
    }
```

Also, `inputpass` should be of type `std::string`

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
int inputpass
```

to

```
string inputpass
```

As your password is a string, not an integer.

Also, your class is full of errors! It should probably look something like this:

```
class MyVar
{

    public:
        MyVar(){
            cout << "this is constructor" << endl;
        }
        bool accesscheckpass(string x){
            return checkpass(x);
        }

    private:
        bool checkpass(string x){
            if(x == "password"){
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, what you need for this, it isn't the best code for this, but it works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class MyVar
{

public:
    MyVar(){
        cout << "this is constructor" << endl;
    }
    bool accesscheckpass(string x){
        return checkpass(x);
    }

private:
    bool checkpass(string x){
        string pass = "password";
        for(int i = 0; i < x.length();i++)
            if(x[i]!=pass[i])
                return false;
        return true;
    }
    };

    int main()
    {
string inputpass;
cout << "please enter your password\n" << endl;
getline(cin, inputpass);
MyVar MyAccess;

if(MyAccess.accesscheckpass(inputpass) == true){
    cout << "welcome user 1" << endl;
}else{
    cout << "get lost !" << endl;
}
```

}

Answer (score -2):

you read chars form `std::cin`. You need to parse then these chars to an integer.

Comment: lol, what a shame mistake i make, now i have edit it and convert the inputpass into string, but this error come again..

error: invalid operands of types ‘void’ and ‘bool’ to binary ‘operator==’|

Comment: @MohdShahril read the other well explained answers. Luchian congratulations for your vote and your comment...